# bash - array expansion and function calls

Tags: arrays, bash, variable-expansion

**SETUP:**

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

**TEST:**

```
check_this() { echo "   FIRST: {$1} SECOND: {$2} THIRD: {$3}"; }

foo=(1 2 3)
expression="${foo[@]}"
echo "via expression:"
check_this "$expression"
echo "directly:"
check_this "${foo[@]}"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
via expression:
   FIRST: {1 2 3} SECOND: {} THIRD: {}
directly:
   FIRST: {1} SECOND: {2} THIRD: {3}
```

**QUESTION(s):**

- what is happening here?
- why does `"${foo[@]}"` not expand to a single string?
- how can I make the `directly` case above behave the `via variable` case?
- Please, explain what a construct `${foo[*]}` and `${foo[@]}` actually is and what the quoting operation does to it.

Comment: `check_this "${foo[*]}"`, because `foo` is an array, not a string?

Comment: Please add a valid shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: See the [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html) section of the bash manual, or try `bash -c "LESS='+/^\ *Special\ Parameters' man bash"` in your terminal. Dont forget the [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) section of the manual too.

Comment: @Jetchisel You mean `@`?

Comment: @Jetchisel: would you mind to post an official answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - what is happening here?
> - why does "${foo[@]}" not expand to a single string?

Because that's the explicitly defined behavior -- and a very useful one.  When an array-valued variable indexed by `@` is expanded inside double quotes, the result is a separate word for each element, or nothing if there are no elements.

> - how can I make the directly case above behave the via variable case?

By using `"${foo[*]}"` instead of `"${foo[@]}"`.

> - Please, explain what a construct ${foo[*]} and ${foo[@]} actually is and what the quoting operation does to it.

Both `${foo[*]}` and `${foo[@]}` represent a sequence of the elements of array-valued variable `foo`.  They differ only with respect to their behavior when expanded inside double quotes, exactly as you are exploring.

When expanded inside double quotes, `${foo[*]}` gives you a single string containing a list of all the elements, separated by the first character in `$IFS` (usually a space).  If there are no elements then the result is equivalent to an empty pair of quotes (`""`).  This is approximately as if you had instead written `"${foo[0]} ${foo[1]} ${foo[2]} ..."`.

When expanded inside double quotes, `${foo[@]}` gives you a separate string for each element.  If there are no elements then the result is equivalent to nothing at all.  This is approximately as if you had instead written `"${foo[0]}" "${foo[1]}" "${foo[2]}" ...`.  Of the two, this is usually the one you want in practice.

These differences are analogous to those between `$*` and `$@`.

Perhaps it would be a mnemonic aid to associate `*` with "all" and `@` with "each".

Answer (score 2):

`"${foo[@]}"` expands to a *list of words*, one per array element. For this instance, it is equivalent to a list of three-word:

```
"${foo[0]}" "${foo[1]}" "${foo[2]}"
```

In contrast, the expansion `"${foo[*]}"` yields *one word*:

```
"${foo[0]} ${foo[1]} ${foo[2]}"
```

which is the concatenation of all array elements with the first character of `IFS` between them (I assume here the value of `IFS` is `$' \t\n'`, that is its default value).

The simple assignment `expression="${foo[@]}"` is an interesting case. Since word splitting isn't performed on expansions in simple assignments,

```
expression="${foo[@]}"
expression=${foo[@]}
expression="${foo[*]}"
expression=${foo[*]}
```

are all equivalent. As an aside, in order to create a copy of an array, array assignment syntax can be used like this:

```
bar=("${foo[@]}")
```

In order to get the same output as that of `check_this "$expression"`, you can replace the `@` with `*` in `check_this "${foo[@]}"`:

```
check_this "${foo[*]}"
```